# ASP.NET MVC: Action that is only called by other actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to make a GET action that only runs if it is called by another action, so not if the user types the URL in the address bar. What can I check to determine whether this is the case?

Comment: Wait...  couldn't the user just type in the first actions url?

Comment: I'm doing some validation on the first action that is shared between some actions, so it's fine if they do that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You may decorate the action with the [ChildActionOnlyAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.childactiononlyattribute.aspx).

```
  [ChildActionOnly]
  public ActionResult Menu() {
    var menu = GetMenuFromSomewhere();
      return PartialView(menu);
  }
```

You may then use the RenderAction() and Action() Html helpers as usual and the action cannot be called by URL.

These are new to MVC 2, but from the tags I assume that you are already using that.

Sample: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx

Answer (score 12):

Make that action's acces modifier private. Since it's a private method, it's not an action method and cannot be called by URL:

```
private ActionResult PrivateAction()
{
    return View("SomeView");
}
```

Then call it from an action method:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
    if(someCondition)
        return PrivateAction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andras Decorating actions with `[ChildActionOnly]` prevents from calling action via ajax and that's necessary in some scenarios. About @ajbeaven question you right but in ajax calling situation I think that is best to decorate action with `[HttpPost]` attribute.

Good Luck